# Docker deployment ignores the styles under the assets folder of Vuejs/Nuxtjs app but works perfectly locally using npm run dev

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a web application developed using `Vuejs/Nuxtjs`. The web application has a Vue Component page named `Design.vue` under `pages/Design.vue`. This Vue component uses the styles from the `assets/css/drawflow.css`. Everything works perfectly fine when I run the application locally using the command `npm run dev` and access the application using `http://localhost:5000/`. I checked the sources by inspecting on Google Chrome and I see the styles page listed there.

Now, If I try to deploy the same application using the `Docker`, I see that my `Design.vue` page is not getting the styles from the `assets/css/drawflow.css`. I tried to inspect in Google Chrome for that page and when I see the `sources`, I do not see the required style sheet.

Not sure what's happening and why the styles under the assets folder are not accessible via Docker. Can someone please let me know what needs to be changed here?

Following is the way I am accessing the styles in `pages/Design.vue`:

```
<style>
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jerosoler/Drawflow@0.0.48/dist/drawflow.min.css";
@import "~/assets/css/drawflow.css";
<!-- @import "@/assets/css/drawflow.css"; -->
</style>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with three.js assets. 
My approach was to store them in public folder, after that they we're known by the container. Try storing it in public/assets

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. The issue was happening because of the styles provided in the CDN link: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jerosoler/Drawflow@0.0.48/dist/drawflow.min.css`.

For some reason, docker was not making requests to this file due to which styles from this file were ignored. I added those styles within my `drawflow.css` file and added a single style. This worked perfectly fine.

```
<style>
@import "~/assets/css/drawflow.css";
</style>
```